# How to pass an argument from the SKLearn initializer class to the entry_point (py.file)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to setup a training job in Sagemaker using SKitLearn. When I initialize the SKLearn class, I am looking to also add a passable argument which will be referenced in the train.py (entry_point). The argument I want to pass is a model_type string such as args.model_type='classification' or args.model_type='regression'.

```
    sklearn_model = SKLearn(
        entry_point=train.py (I WANT TO PASS args.model_type into this PY.file, HOW??),
        role=role,
        train_instance_type=region_instance_dict[region],
        py_version="py3",
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
        train_max_run=MaxRuntimeInSeconds
        )
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You could specify your args using the `hyperparameters` with the estimator constructor: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/estimator.py#L1314

In your case, the item in your hyperparameters dict could be
{"--model-type": }